# ActiveMQ Artemis and MQTT bridging

Tags: mqtt, activemq-artemis

The Mosquitto MQTT broker offers a feature to bridge two MQTT brokers for publishing and subscribing of messages. This is described [here](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-bridge-configuration/).

When any client publishes messages to ActiveMQ Artemis broker I want these messages to be automatically published to another MQTT broker based on a configured topic mapping. I want to know if this is possible via a feature built-in to ActiveMQ Artemis or possibly via a broker plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artemis does have bridging functionality for the "core" protocol as well as a generic JMS bridge implementation, but it has **no** MQTT bridging functionality built-in. Also, I don't think it would be a good idea to implement this via a broker plugin for two reasons. First, a plugin really should be as low-latency as possible as any latency from a plugin will impact any other client. Second, the structure of the plugin architecture would not lend itself to this task; in fact, I'm not sure it would be possible at all.

That said, I see two possible solutions:

1. Create a Camel route to do the bridging work and deploy it as a WAR to the embedded Jetty instance shipped with Artemis. The Camel route will run within the same JVM as the Artemis broker so no additional processes/management will be necessary. Camel is easy to use and extremely powerful. There is [an example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/standard/camel) of how do this that ships with Artemis.
2. Deploy a Mosquitto broker in bridge mode to move the messages between brokers.

Comment: Does it mean that ActiveMQ broker does not have any option for bridging like mosquitto?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. If you believe this answer is correct please mark it as such to help other users in the future who may also have this question. If you believe it is not correct please clarify via a comment.

Comment: I have updated my question to be more clear. But I understand your answer.